# Component reload increase amount of HTTP requests

Tags: angular, http, routes, request, components

I'm building Angular (5.2.2) application, for ImpressPages, and I have optimisation problem with HTTP requests. My application structure looks like below:

[Angular Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23CGz.png)

**container.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="layout">
  <app-news *ngIf="layout == 'NewsComponent'" [hidden]="layout != 'NewsComponent'"></app-news>
  <app-main *ngIf="layout == 'MainComponent'" [hidden]="layout != 'MainComponent'"></app-main>
  <app-home *ngIf="layout == 'HomeComponent'" [hidden]="layout != 'HomeComponent'"></app-home>
</div>
```

**container.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-container',
  templateUrl: './container.component.html',
})
export class ContainerComponent{
  layout: string;

  constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.data.subscribe((response: {layout: string}) => {
      this.layout = response.layout;
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
}
```

**main.component.ts**

Other components like Home, News looks the same - only URLs for API change and layouts in HTML

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { ServerService } from '../../services/server.service';
import { SeoService } from '../../services/seo.service';
import { Config } from '../../config';


interface pageData {
  banner: string;
  data: any;
  html: string;
  text: string;
  title: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  providers: [Config, ServerService, SeoService]
})
export class MainComponent {

  URL: string;
  langUrl: string;
  active: string;
  pageData: pageData;
  headerText: Object;



  constructor(private config: Config, private route: ActivatedRoute, private service: ServerService, private seo: SeoService) {
    this.URL = this.config.URL;
    this.langUrl = this.config.getLanguage();

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {


    this.route.params.subscribe( params => {

      if(params.lang != this.langUrl) {
        this.langUrl = params.lang;
      }


      let siteTitle = params.index;

      if(typeof siteTitle != 'undefined') {
          siteTitle = siteTitle.replace('.html', ' ');
          siteTitle = siteTitle.replace(/-/g,' ');
      }


      this.service.getResponse(`${this.URL}/getContent/${params.index}/${this.langUrl}/0`).subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
            this.pageData = response;
            this.seo.generateTags({
              lang: this.langUrl,
              title : siteTitle,
              image : `${this.URL}/file/repository/${this.pageData.banner}`,
              slug : params.index
          })
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
      );
   });
  }
}
```

And there is the problem. When I'm loading site first time HTTP requests looks like:

[HTTP requests #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvyMT.jpg)

And then, when I'm going to other page with other layout (other component). HTTP requests increase by one, every time when I'm trying to enter and leave that page.  First enter :

[HTTP requests #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfOH8.jpg)

And one more time :

[HTTP requests #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kDCw.jpg)

(everytime I clear Network tab for it)

Is there any better way to implement my idea ? I need to manage components on the same route depends which layout API will return, it have to be dynamic. I can't create links like /home/:lang/:pageName or /main/:lang/:pageName. URLs have to be like in ImpressPages CMS.

(service-worker don't cache data from API - I didn't buy HTTPS yet, don't look at it)

I hope I've explained it good. 
Thank You for answers.

**EDIT**

I have a problem now with that dynamic components loading (https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) . When I'm trying to do it by **createComponent()** method it's increasing my components amount by one. When I'm trying to do it by **insert()** method I'm getting error :

```
`Cannot set property 'viewContainerParent' of undefined`
```

Here is my code:

```
import { Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


import { NewsComponent } from '../components/news/news.component';
import { MainComponent } from '../components/main/main.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../components/home/home.component';

import { ContainerDirective } from '../directives/container.directive';

// Directive
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';



export const entryComponentsMap = {
  'NewsComponent': NewsComponent,
  'MainComponent': MainComponent,
  'HomeComponent': HomeComponent
};  // Add Layout here


@Component({
  selector: 'app-container',
  templateUrl: './container.component.html',
})



export class ContainerComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef}) container : ViewContainerRef;

  layout: any;
  component: any;

  constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute, private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe((response: {layout: string}) => {
      this.layout = response.layout;
      this.loadComponent(this.layout);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error); 
    })

  }

  loadComponent(layout) {
      let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(entryComponentsMap[layout]);
      this.container.insert(entryComponentsMap[layout], 0);
      this.component = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);


  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this)
    this.component.destroy();
  }
}
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: You probably forgot to unsubscribe from an observable somewhere

Comment: Yes, you are right, but is there better way to dynamic components loading? I read about this https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader but will it increase app performence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. Routing params subscribe was loading twice. Making a requests from every 3 components loaded at one time. I've just used unsubsribe() and reduce api calls for one when component is in view.

Working example :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { Config } from "../../config";
import { ServerService } from "../../services/server.service";
import { SeoService } from "../../services/seo.service";
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';
import { ISubscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';





interface pageData {
  banner: string;
  data: any;
  html: string;
  text: string;
  title: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-news',
  templateUrl: './news.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news.component.less'],
  providers : [Config, ServerService, SeoService],
})


export class NewsComponent implements OnDestroy {
  subscription: ISubscription;
  subscriptionHTTP: ISubscription;

  URL: string;
  langUrl: string;
  active: string;
  pageData: pageData;
  headerText: Object;



  constructor(private config: Config, private route: ActivatedRoute, private service: ServerService, private seo: SeoService) {
    this.URL = this.config.impressURL;
    this.langUrl = this.config.getLanguage();

    this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe( params => {

      if(params.lang != this.langUrl) {
        this.langUrl = params.lang;
      }

      let siteTitle = params.index;

      if(typeof siteTitle != 'undefined') {
          siteTitle = siteTitle.replace('.html', ' ');
          siteTitle = siteTitle.replace(/-/g,' ');
      }


     this.subscriptionHTTP = this.service.getResponse(`${this.URL}/getContent/${params.index}/${this.langUrl}/0`).subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
            this.pageData = response;
            this.seo.generateTags({
              lang: this.langUrl,
              title : siteTitle,
              image : `${this.URL}/file/repository/${this.pageData.banner}`,
              slug : params.index
          })
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
      ); 
   });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.subscription) this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    if(this.subscriptionHTTP)  this.subscriptionHTTP.unsubscribe();
  }

  hideOnClick(element, target) {
    element.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove('in');
  }
}
```

I have tried this way also : https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader, but my way is much faster. Components are loading at the beginning, not on route change.